# Naming row and column in table

Tags: tables, xtable

I want to create the table like this (with row and column each names individually and also in a group):
[image]
I can create the table, but I do not know how to write those column and row names. How can I selectively remove the vertical line on table in some cells?

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80392/bracket-covering-only-a-part-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{($-1,C$)}` to selectively remove/add vertical lines.
Also, to merge two rows in a cell, you can use `multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*4c}
& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$p_{2}$}\\
& & $F$ &$D$ \\\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{$p_{1}$}& $F$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{($1-C$,$1-C$)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{($-C,1$)} \\\cline{3-4}
& $D$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{($-1,C$)} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{($0,0$)}\\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Here you have started with no vertical bars and built whenever necessary. Can we start with all vertical bars and remove wherever necessary?

Comment: @DurgaDatta: Yes. you have to use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{($-1,C$)}`. Note `{c}` without vertical bars. But here it will add too many `\multicolumns, an over kill.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep,cell-space-limits=3pt}
$\begin{NiceArray}{cccc}
                   &   & \Block{1-2}{p_2} \\
                   &   & F         & D \\
\Block{2-1}{p_1} & F & \Block[hvlines]{2-2}{}
                         (1-C,1-C) & (-C,1)  \\
                   & D & (-1,C)    & (0,0) \\
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]