# How to use multicolumn and multirow in a table that uses tabular?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80504/naming-row-and-column-in-table?newreg=cacebe02efd44bccbaee840d4233e5fb) I learned how to create a table with labels for the rows and columns.    But, I'm still struggling to get this to look exactly how I'd like.

I'd like to extend this solution to an arbitrary number of columns, for example I tried to extend it to 3 columns in the latex code below.  But, it doesn't seem that I'm able to get the lines to also extend.  Could someone help push me the rest of the way?

```
\begin{tabular}{*6c}
& &\multicolumn{4}{c}{$P$}\\
& & $A$ &$B$ & $C$ \\\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}{*}& $A$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$0$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$500$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$500$} \\\cline{3-4}
& $D$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{($100$)} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{($200$)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{($200$)}\\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks.  I've enjoyed many of your answers on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption text here}
\[
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={*{4}{c}}, 
  hline{3-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
  vline{2-Z}={3-Z}{solid},
  }
& \SetCell[c=3]{c} P \\
& A & B & C \\
A     & 0      & 500    & 500    \\
D     & (100)  &(200)   & (200)  \\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{If you need one column less}
\[
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={*{3}{c}}, 
  hline{3-Z}={2-Z}{solid},
  vline{2-Z}={3-Z}{solid},
  }
& \SetCell[c=2]{c} P \\
& A & B  \\
A     & 0      & 500    \\
D     & (100)  &(200)   \\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption text here}
\centering
$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc}
  & \Block{1-3}{P}\\[1ex]
  & A      & B      & C & \\ 
A & \Block[hvlines]{2-3}{}
    0      & 500    & 500    \\ 
D & (100)  &(200)   & (200)  \\ 
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Your code specifies the table as having 6 columns; however, the screenshot suggest that there are just 4 columns. I can't detect a need for `\multirow`. And, since all of the table's contents seem to "math-y", I'd employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.

The following code makes the necessary adjustments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped "look"
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption text here}
\centering
$\begin{array}{*{4}{c|}}
\mc{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P}\\[1ex]
\mc{} & \mc{A} & \mc{B} & \mc{C} \\ \cline{2-4}
A     & 0      & 500    & 500    \\ \cline{2-4}
D     & (100)  &(200)   & (200)  \\ \cline{2-4}
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now, is there a way to add a caption in this `array` environment?  I'm not familiar with the array environment.  In `tabular` it's pretty easy, but when I try to insert `\caption{....}` after `\begin{array}`, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @underdog987 - I've edited my answer to add some LaTeX code that (a) embeds the `array` in a `table` environment and (b) provides a dummy `\caption` statement. Note that it's the `table` environment, not the `tabular` environment, that provides the `\caption` machinery.

Comment: Thanks it works!!  I'm trying to combine the the `array` that you gave me above, with a table (similar to the one in my original question) in a single figure.  Ideally the table would be one subfigure, and the array would be a separate subfigure, and a caption for each one.  I tried it myself, but I'm getting the error `Not in outer par mode.`.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm trying to avoid starting a new question unless you think it's necessary.  Thanks for your help @Mico.

Comment: @underdog987 - So, basically, you want to place a `table` (with either a `tabular` or an `array` inside) next to a `figure`? Please confirm.

Comment: There are two things I want to display:  a table (created using tabular), and an array (which apparently can be wrapped into a table environment as you showed above).   
 Perhaps "figure" isn't the right word, but I just want them displayed next to each other with a separate caption for each, and one caption for both.  I hope I'm using the terminology correctly here.   I saw your answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294596/309592), and so I believe this can be done using `subtable`, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @underdog987 - We appear to have missed each other in the chat room. Anyway, here is what I wrote: "I think there may be some confusion because of LaTeX terminology/jargon. 'tabular' and 'array' environments are both "tables" in ordinary (non-LaTeX) parlance. A LaTeX 'table' is a particular type of a LaTeX "float" (sorry, more jargon). A 'table' environment generally contains one or more tabular and/or array environments. If you load the 'subcaption' package, you can make use of its 'subtable' machinery." (continued)

Comment: @underdog987 -- (continued) If you want, you can place two `subtable` environments side by side, and make each one contain a `tabular` or `array` envrionment along with an associated \caption directive."