# How to add a tag to each row and column of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to assign a tag to each row and column of a matrix. Currently, I have only figured out how to create the matrix:

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \{q_0\} & \{q_0, q_1\} \\
        \{q_2\} & \emptyset \\
        \emptyset & \emptyset
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

Which yields the following matrix:

[image: Matrix generated by LaTex]

I need to add q_0, q_1 and q_2 tags to the rows and 0 and 1 tags to the columns as shown in the image below.

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/row-spacing-in-kbordermatrix?rq=1, actualyy, your question is duplicate to it. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution with package `blkarray`  isn't mentioned in the above link, I'll add it here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{blockarray}{rcc}
   & 0 & 1 \\
\begin{block}{r[cc]}
  q_0 & \{q_0\} & \{q_0,q_1\}\bigstrut[t] \\
q_1 & \{q_2\} & \varnothing \\
q_2 & \varnothing & \varnothing \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]